# Marking white borders with black marker

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Is it legal in competitive play to fill in the border of white-bordered MtG cards with black marker?

Which marker would be best to use, and why?

Comment: Why would you do this? As far as I know, white bordered cards are still tournament legal. I would be worried about "bleed" to the edge of the card so that it's considered marked when viewed from the back/side.

Comment: cause City of brass has to match with all the bordered cards in my deck

Comment: Tried to clean up the question. What features are you looking for in a marker, blackness, non-bleed, etc.?

Comment: non-bleed hopefully

Comment: Opaque-backed sleeves should prevent card-marking allegations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, but only if the head judge agrees. The [Mtg Tournament rules](http://wiki.internationalmagicjudges.net/index.php?title=Magic_Tournament_Rules#3.3_Authorized_Cards) require that the card has white or black borders (no UN cards or World Champion cards), and the alteration cannot make the card marked. As **ghoppe** points out, you might have to worry about bleed unless you use Opaque card sleeves. If you choose to do this, a judge will likely still be called to verify that the cards aren't marked for randomization purposes if sleeves aren't used, and the cards are legal white\black bordered cards and not World Champion cards in either case.

Answer (score 8):

Not going into detail with the tournament rules, I can say that I have done this myself, for aesthetics only. (my eyes got annoyed by the white borders + OCD)

After testing some, I found that these four markers were the way to go since they dried fast and didn't smudge easily :

[image: Markes I use]